# Оптимизирует ли это код?

Tags: ресурсы, c, оптимизация, c++, производительность

Имеется 2 цикла:

```
for (i = 0; i < a + 1; i++) { }
```

и

```
b = a + 1;
for (i = 0; i < b; i++) { }
```

Вычисляет ли процессор по новой при каждом прохождении цикла значение `a + 1`?
То есть, по другому говоря, с точки зрения экономии ресурсов код №2 лучше №1?

Comment: Зависит от компилятора и указанного ему уровня оптимизации.

Ну и, это субъективно — но если это не какое-то супер-критичное узкое место где *реально* нужно быстро работать, я бы не стал жертвовать читаемостью кода в пользу таких микрооптимизаций.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Вот результат gcc-4.6.1 на x86-64:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < a + 1; i++) {
        printf("iteration: %d\n", i);
    }
}
```

Собираем `gcc -O2 -g -Wall -std=c99 -o test test.c`

В gdb видим вот такое:

```
0x400440 <main>       push   %rbx
0x400441 <main+1>     xor    %ebx,%ebx
0x400443 <main+3>     nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
0x400448 <main+8>     mov    %ebx,%edx
0x40044a <main+10>    xor    %eax,%eax
0x40044c <main+12>    mov    $0x40063c,%esi
0x400451 <main+17>    mov    $0x1,%edi
0x400456 <main+22>    add    $0x1,%ebx
0x400459 <main+25>    callq  0x400430 <__printf_chk@plt>
0x40045e <main+30>    cmp    $0xb,%ebx
0x400461 <main+33>    jne    0x400448 <main+8>
0x400463 <main+35>    xor    %eax,%eax
0x400465 <main+37>    pop    %rbx
0x400466 <main+38>    retq
```

Т.е. видим, что компилятор сам все прекрасно довел до константы 11 (см. `main+30`).

С другой стороны, вызовы функций стоит делать руками. Вот такое gcc уже не потянул, `printf` в функции сбил его с толку:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo() {
    printf("called foo\n");
    return 10;
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < foo() + 1; i++) {
        printf("iteration: %d\n", i);
    }
}
```

Там уже `call` на каждую итерацию.

---

Premature optimization is the root of all evil —Donald Knuth

Comment: Отличный пример.

Answer (score 4):

Если код, находящийся внутри цикла не имеет побочных эффектов и компилятору это известно, то он может оптимизироваться и выполниться только один раз. Если функция импортируется, например из dll, то компилятор не может знать что внутри, и будет вызывать её на каждой итерации. То же самое будет, если этот код изменяет внешнюю переменную.

Answer (score 3):

Тут все зависит от компилятора, какой машинный код он сделает. Современные компиляторы (типа gcc) такие ситуации хорошо оптимизируют. Т.е. они все-таки вычислят перед циклом сумму и уже с ней будут делать сравнение.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь ясно.